# Creating a half Byte dictionary of hexadecimals - without built in functions

Tags: python, dictionary, binary

base_destination (dict_create - the function receives as input the target base (8 or 16) as an integer
And returns a dictionary so that the keys in the dictionary are the binary representation of the number and the values are the representation at the base
The target obtained, the keys must contain 4 digits in binary representation as a string.
For example:
For the input - 8
{"0000": 0, "0001": 1, "0010": 2, "0011": 3, "0100": 4, "0101": 5, "0110": 6, "0111": 7} - The dictionary will be accepted

- Do not write the dictionary manually

My code:

```
def pad_zeros(binary_as_str, length):
    subtraction = length - len(binary_as_str)
    return "0" * subtraction + binary_as_str

 def binary_add_one(binary_as_str):
    binary_string = pad_zeros(binary_as_str, 4)
    for i in range(len(binary_string) - 1, - 1, - 1):
        if binary_string[i] == "0":
            return binary_string[0:i] + "1" + "0" * (len(binary_string) - i - 1)
    return "1" + 0 * binary_string


def number_to_letter():
    str = ""
    for i in range(7):
        str += chr(65 + i)
    return str


def create_dict(destination_base):
    dicti = {}
    key_list = []
    starter = "0000"
    for i in range(destination_base):
        if i < 10:
            key_list.append(starter)
            starter = binary_add_one(starter)
            dicti[key_list[i]] = i
        else:
            key_list.append(starter)
            starter = binary_add_one(starter)
            dicti[key_list[i]] = number_to_letter()[i - 10]
    return dicti


print(create_dict(16))
```

It works great, but the problem is, I dont know how to do it without putting the list..
Any tip on how to do without using list + int + ascii to do it? without built in functions...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the literal list, change the definition of `value_list` to

```
value_list=[x for x in range(10)]+["{:X}".format(x) for x in range(10,16)]
```

Or are you not allowed to use `range()` and `str.format()` either?

Comment: Hey, sorry its not for me list comprehensions...
and by the way, I made a new code, can you tell me if its good? without the built in list.
Its just that I dont know if I am allowed to do it...

Comment: I will edit in a minute.

Comment: to be honest, range and str.format we are allowed. but list comprehension is not for me... I want a code I can understand and I dont really want a solution. Is what I did good? is it according to the question? my problem is that I dont know if its allowed what I did... the rules of the question are not really understanble, I can ask, but he will answer me only in 2~3 days... which is why I opened here.

Comment: If you can't use list comprehensions, then how about `value_list = list(range(10))+list('ABCDEF')`? Your modified code works, but it seems to me that you are being forced into writing obscure and convoluted code and I'm having trouble seeing the educational value of that.

Comment: I can use list comprehensions. about the value_list,  I know it works, but the problem is not whether the code works, it works great, but if its good according to the rules of the question. it said not to do built in for the dictionary, but I dont know if its built in ( and in my new code I don't have the list anymore, I did a new thing with ascii and such, so it wont be built in, but I still do not know if its allowed... ) the rules are not understandable

Comment: I just solved it, asked a friend. Thanks anyway :)